# HTACCESS rewrite url /$USERNAME to /user/profile/USERNAME

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, codeigniter, preg-match

I have a url

```
website.com/user/profile/USERNAME
```

I want I want to rewrite it to this...

```
website.com/$USERNAME
```

so when someone type in website.com/$USERNAME it will display this page content website.com/user/profile/USERNAME

USERNAME here can be anything...

Any help suggestions?

Comment: Try this code: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user/profile/USERNAME=$1  i am not sure but it can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

> so when someone type in website.com/$USERNAME it will display this page content website.com/user/profile/USERNAME

So you want to rewrite website.com/$USERNAME (in the request) so the webserver returns the content at website.com/user/profile/USERNAME (You said the opposite before).

If USERNAME can be anything then why do you not simply change the document root to $CURRENT_DOCUMENT_ROOT/user/profile/ If this is not the solution to your problem then we need to know *why* you can't do this in order to work out what the *correct* rewrite should be.